# State Management design

Tags: management, state, session, aws

I am working a product which have 
WebApi 
Android/ios app
Web app

WebApi is hosted in AWS EC2 .

Currently we have requirement like we need to mantain state. Take one scenario. App have 4 pages. User filled up to 2 pages and went.
When re returns (may be in app or app in another mobile or web) he needs to continue from the 3 page.

For this we need to maintain each state. As we are using WebApi, I am confused how to design this.

My thinking:
Each page or where ever want as state, client need to sent that as a session to AWS redid.
This will.make other clients can access the session basedd on user and can access the API accordingy
I think we don't want include any sessions related things in web API

Please suggest better design for this

Comment: What happens after a user fills up all 4 pages?  Do you persist the user's pages long term, or throw them away quickly, or, hold them in memory until the server is restarted?

Comment: My thinking is to delete that after user finished the full flow. Please suggest if any best practices

Comment: Why not just store it in the app?